# Yii. Use updateAll without exact setting value of parameter

Tags: php, activerecord, yii

How can I update rows using **updateAll** or **updateCounters** without exact setting value of parameter?

**What I have:**

```
Ratings::model()->updateAll(
            array( 'o' => $howAdd, 'last' => $ins),
            "AND type = {$type} AND num = {$num}");
```

**What I need:** set value for 'o' as **'o' = 'o' + $howAdd**.

Answer (score 0):

Not so sure you can achieve this with updateAll

However if your value $howadd is integer
you could try to take look at updateCounters.